# How to set element to the right in html?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set the toggle buttons to the right. float, right : 0, align-self is not working for me.

What am I doing wrong ?

The picture is at the end.

HTML:

```
 <div if:true={showCards} class='main-container'>
        <div class="main-container-top"> 

            <p class="currs-available"> {trainingPlans.length} {headerLabel} </p>

            <lightning-input 
                class="search slds-p-vertical_small" 
                type="search" 
                onchange={handleSearch} 
                variant="label-hidden"
                placeholder="Search" >
            </lightning-input>

         <c-toggle-button
            class="toggle"
            buttons={toggleData}
            ontoggleswitch={handleToggleSwitch}
            default=1>
         </c-toggle-button>

        </div>
.............
......
.....
```

and relevant CSS:

```
.main-container{
    background: #f5f5f5;
}

.main-container-top{
    display: flex;
}

.currs-available{
    width: 33%;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 9px 0 0 20px;
}

.toggle{
    width: 33%;
}
```

[Image of element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ILvV.png)

Comment: margin-left: auto;

Comment: You can use `justify-content:space-between`. This makes items in a flex box align to the outer edges, as long as that `main-container-top` uses the full width of the page.

Comment: Float does not work in a flex container

Answer (score -1):

You can use `position: absolute;` if you're using `right: 0;`

Although, the `display: flex;` will be ignored